# place picker close immediately after activity start (google places api)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

i have created a simple program to use google maps api and google places api . the google maps api is used to place marker and get lat long and other basic functionality .
the places api is triggered through a option in option bar on top right . the intent is triggered and then it immediately closed . with out returning any result or even letting me select a location .
i have given my main class, build , manifest files below .
please do tell any extra info required and suggest any solution .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,  OnMapReadyCallback {

LocationManager locationManager;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
MapFragment map;
GoogleMap googleMap_local;
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    checkGps();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();

    map = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.pick_place) {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(MainActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location loc = LocationServices
            .FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + loc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap_local = googleMap;
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            if (latLng != null) {
                Geocoder geocoder;
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(featurename).snippet("sagar"));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLng)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .zoom(14)
                        .tilt(30)
                        .build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(MainActivity.this);
    super.onPause();
}

public void checkGps() {
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please enable gps.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, MainActivity.this);

            LatLng latLng=place.getLatLng();

            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            googleMap_local.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(featurename).snippet("sagar"));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLng)
                    .bearing(0)
                    .zoom(14)
                    .tilt(30)
                    .build();

            googleMap_local.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBUBS4XFq4X9WZ8b35KTMV2LWJoZjtK2wI" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

**Log**

```
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueDump: [unnamed-15882-1] checkBackupCnt: str:[none]
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueDump: [unnamed-15882-1] matchName: str:[none] mName:unnamed-15882-1 
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueDump: [unnamed-15882-1] matchCName: 0
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueDump: [unnamed-15882-1] match result:0
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueDump: [unnamed-15882-1] parse * isMatched:0 backupCnt:0
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:15882) setConsumerName: unnamed-15882-1
02-17 16:52:45.500 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:15882) setDefaultBufferSize: width=720 height=1006
02-17 16:52:45.509 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/GLConsumer: [unnamed-15882-1] attachToContext
02-17 16:52:45.522 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: SEND_RESULT handled : 0 / ResultData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 results[ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=2, data=null}]}
02-17 16:52:45.523 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}} finished=false
02-17 16:52:45.524 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}}
02-17 16:52:45.524 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
02-17 16:52:45.524 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}} with isForward=false
02-17 16:52:45.524 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{8c93ef1 com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1d5f7982 V.E..... R....... 0,0-720,1280}
02-17 16:52:45.525 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}}
02-17 16:52:45.525 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) connect(P): api=1 producer=(15882:com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi) producerControlledByApp=true
02-17 16:52:45.525 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:52:45.527 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8d4f9c0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) cancelBuffer: slot 0
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=5, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=2
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) setBufferCount: count = 5
02-17 16:52:45.536 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
02-17 16:52:45.538 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d4f9c0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:45.540 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:52:45.547 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8d4f9c0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:45.592 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:52:45.598 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8eb7ca8) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:45.614 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0xb8d4f9c0
02-17 16:52:45.675 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ee76b0) (w:640 h:117 s:640 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:45.677 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
02-17 16:52:45.677 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
02-17 16:52:45.677 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
02-17 16:52:45.678 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8ee76b0) (w:640 h:117 s:640 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:45.684 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ee76b0) (w:640 h:117 s:640 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:45.769 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: slot 1 is dropped, handle=0xb8eb7ca8
02-17 16:52:46.264 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8dd11e8) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:47.567 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-17 16:52:47.567 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-17 16:52:47.567 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8ee76b0) (w:640 h:117 s:640 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:49.245 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: fps=0.82 dur=3653.27 max=3476.12 min=22.06
02-17 16:52:49.261 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:52:49.272 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ebdf18) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:49.280 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ebeb20) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:49.309 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:52:49.329 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ec70c0) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:52:49.353 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-17 16:52:49.358 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-17 16:52:49.362 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ee7648) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:56.758 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:52:56.759 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8d96df0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:56.795 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: fps=0.40 dur=7549.95 max=7423.35 min=58.44
02-17 16:52:58.993 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
02-17 16:52:59.040 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:-1,c:15882) disconnect(P): api 1
02-17 16:52:59.040 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:-1,c:15882) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
02-17 16:52:59.040 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8eb7ca8) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:59.041 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8ebdf18) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:59.041 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8ee7648) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:59.042 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d96df0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:52:59.044 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}}
02-17 16:52:59.101 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891
02-17 16:52:59.101 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
02-17 16:52:59.102 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/AbsListView: onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=false, this=com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.n{70c1d90 G.ED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0}
02-17 16:52:59.993 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}}: show=true win=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@2f20fa83
02-17 16:52:59.993 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891
02-17 16:53:05.899 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: SEND_RESULT handled : 0 / ResultData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 results[ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1, result=2, data=Intent { (has extras) }}]}
02-17 16:53:05.900 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}} finished=false
02-17 16:53:05.903 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}}
02-17 16:53:05.903 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
02-17 16:53:05.903 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}} with isForward=false
02-17 16:53:05.903 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{8c93ef1 com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1d5f7982 V.E..... R....... 0,0-720,1280}
02-17 16:53:05.903 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{6e6b2b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891 {com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi.MainActivity}}
02-17 16:53:05.907 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) connect(P): api=1 producer=(15882:com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi) producerControlledByApp=true
02-17 16:53:05.907 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:53:05.911 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/ActivityThread: ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@2cfe5891
02-17 16:53:05.921 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/AbsListView: onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=true, this=com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.n{70c1d90 G.ED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0}
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8dcdc40) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) cancelBuffer: slot 0
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=5, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=2
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) setBufferCount: count = 5
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
02-17 16:53:05.937 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8dcdc40) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:53:05.939 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:53:05.942 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8dcdc40) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:53:05.942 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.widget.LinearLayout{8ac9ddf VFE..... .F...... 0,0-720,112 #7f0d0092 app:id/place_autocomplete_fragment} softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#81810100
02-17 16:53:05.942 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.widget.LinearLayout{8ac9ddf VFE..... .F...... 0,0-720,112 #7f0d0092 app:id/place_autocomplete_fragment} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3f797924 controlFlags=#101
02-17 16:53:05.965 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: fps=0.22 dur=9170.21 max=9136.98 min=33.24
02-17 16:53:05.966 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:53:05.969 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8de1ae0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:53:05.978 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0xb8dcdc40
02-17 16:53:06.101 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8d00c48) (w:156 h:88 s:160 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:53:06.102 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
02-17 16:53:06.102 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
02-17 16:53:06.102 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
02-17 16:53:06.103 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d00c48) (w:156 h:88 s:160 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:53:06.106 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8d00c48) (w:156 h:88 s:160 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:53:06.123 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d4f9c0) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:53:06.514 15882-15882/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/View: Key down dispatch to android.widget.LinearLayout{8ac9ddf VFE..... .F...... 0,0-720,112 #7f0d0092 app:id/place_autocomplete_fragment}, event = KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_A, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=45939106, downTime=45939106, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
02-17 16:53:07.902 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-17 16:53:07.902 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-17 16:53:07.902 15882-15955/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d00c48) (w:156 h:88 s:160 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
02-17 16:53:12.461 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) new GraphicBuffer needed
02-17 16:53:12.466 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8d3bc58) (w:720 h:1006 s:720 f:0x2 u:0x000702)
02-17 16:53:12.489 15882-15945/com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.googleapi I/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-15882-1](this:0xb8cebef0,id:1,api:1,p:15882,c:15882) queueBuffer: fps=0.46 dur=6523.36 max=5544.44 min=12.18
```

Comment: Did you received any error message? can you provide us your logs? Dont forget to enable 'Google Places API for Android' in your Google Developer Console and dont forget to specify your API key in your Android Manifest. Here's a Stackoverflow ticket related to your inquiry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067210/android-place-picker-closes-immediately-after-launch

Comment: i have added log . please do check.

Comment: Have you enable "Places API for Android"? make sure you enable "Places API for Android" and not just "Places API" in the Developer Console. "Places API for Android" will not show up under "APIs & Auth/APIs" because it isnt a popular API (yet). You will have to search for it using the API search box.

Comment: i have indeed enabled it. this api key is perfectly working with my other app for place picker and auto complete .there is some fault with the code . i don't know what is it .

Comment: i got no good response but i found the answer myself and posting here for them who might have the same problem.
keep in mind while creating api key for your app-
1. get your SHA1 key for your particular desktop or laptop.
2. click for android api key.
3. put the correct package name in credentials .
4. enable the api(s) required.
5. wait for few minutes and your api key will be ready to use.

in above case i was having problem with the package name. the package name was from another program and i was just reusing the key which is not good .
create api key for each new package you create.

Comment: @LenovoS90 Thanks a lot! The "Places API for Android" was the issue for me