# Place picker close immediatley after launching ,when downloaded from play store

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

The google place picker is working fine in Debug Apk and Signed apk but when I download it from Play store, the Place picker stops working,it close immediately after open. I have check all the permission required to give in manifest.xml and gradle file . I am using google play services version 10.0.0.
below is my gradle and manifest entires.

in my gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.0'
```

in AndroidManifest:

```
  <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="**************"/>
```

This is kind of weird thing,as it is working fine in signed apk.
Please suggest any solution with reason behind this issue,if it is known to anyone ??

Comment: check here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067210/android-place-picker-closes-immediately-after-launch

Comment: already tried ,and I face this issue only after publishing the app to play store . (it is working fine in signed APK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting failed by trying everything ,
Atlast
I just change 
**Key restriction**  on developer console for my application.

> - None
> - HTTP referrers (web sites)
> - IP addresses
> - Android apps
> - IOS

from Android Apps to None and it works.
This was the only option left. 
If anyone get stuck in same problem,can use this as a temp solution.