# Place API closes immediately after opening

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm a beginner in Android
I'm trying to write apps that use Android Place API.
but when I have a phone connected to the internet this place API closes immediately after opening, when I disconnect the internet and open PlacePicker it didn't  close but when I have open PlacePicker and re-connecting to the internet and typing some search: Can not load search results
I read this:
[Android Place Picker closes immediately after launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067210/android-place-picker-closes-immediately-after-launch)
I checked all the suggestions but all the time it's the same
Logcat has no errors
My English is not well but I have hope you understand me :-)

Below adds the code
Manifests:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/key_api">
    </meta-data>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

java class:

```
 package com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        int     PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
        private Button serchBut;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            serchBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_search);

            serchBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    openSerch();
                }
            });
        }

        public void openSerch () {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

            try {
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(MainActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode ==PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(MainActivity.this, data);
                    String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
                    Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

end logcat:

```
11-19 12:03:55.126 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
11-19 12:03:55.144 8164-8177/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=79
11-19 12:03:55.147 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@5292d3c nm : com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask ic=null
11-19 12:04:26.251 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/ViewRootImpl@f1a1c3f[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-19 12:04:26.337 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/ViewRootImpl@f1a1c3f[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-19 12:04:26.410 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/ViewRootImpl@f1a1c3f[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
11-19 12:04:27.084 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=79
11-19 12:04:27.673 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/ViewRootImpl@f1a1c3f[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
11-19 12:04:27.673 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/ViewRootImpl@f1a1c3f[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -1518911488}
11-19 12:04:27.674 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@cb07d7d nm : com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask ic=null
11-19 12:04:27.674 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
11-19 12:04:27.686 8164-8164/com.example.dawid.recruitmenttask D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=85
```

maybe some of you have an idea

Comment: You've missed the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: I add this and don't work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have enabled the **Places API**, and *NOT* the Maps API:

[image: Places API]

Which is a common mistake. Find it on the [Google Cloud Library](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup). 
Then create and add the API Key to your manifest. You can follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) for restricting it the access to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the apiKey like in the Androidmanifest Application tag

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD9MY-KYYF-lSXs_mOAZHY"/>
```

Comment: Dunno try Uninstall/reinstall app clean project

Comment: I try this but not help