# Place Autocomplete closes immediately after launch

Tags: android, google-maps

i have implemented auto place search(`autocomplete intent`) in my apps . it was working well few days ago but now the popup search intent closing immediately after open. I have google it but found no answer. I have followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067210/android-place-picker-closes-immediately-after-launch) but it did not work. What is the problem? can anyone help me to solve this please.

Comment: post the logcat error ...use device not emulater

Comment: i used samsung J7 and asus. no error showing.

Comment: even i did debug , but no error or warning showing.

Comment: that is weird ...check the docs it may be you exceed the search limit

Comment: no. i did not search for more than 20 today. same thing worked few days ago too but now acting like this

Comment: read this https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage

Comment: i did not search for a single time today because of abnormal closing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173003/discussion-between-al-tegani-and-aaa).

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem by myself. The error occurred due to the update of android studio. after update, the SHA1 key was changed so i just adjust it to the google console and all works fine again.